# SQL query to get the number of customers who purchased on multiple dates and also bought multiple products

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble coming up with a query to get the number of customers who purchased on multiple dates and bought multiple products.

We're given a table of product purchases. Each row in the table represents an individual user product purchase.if the customer purchased two things on the same day that does not count as an upsell as they were purchased within a similar timeframe.

'transactions' table:

| column | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | integer |
| user_id | integer |
| created_at | datetime |
| product_id | integer |
| quantity | integer |

I tried in this way

```
select count(*) from (select user_id, count(date) from (SELECT user_id, DATE(created_at) AS date
FROM transactions
GROUP BY 1) S
group by 1
having count(date)>1) A
```

Comment: please do not share image. Share complete table structure with scripts of create table and sample insert script.

Comment: @AlonEitan is this correct now?

Answer (score 2):

So if a customer purchases at least two things ever, on different days they were upsold?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
  (
    SELECT null x FROM transactions GROUP BY user_id HAVING MIN(DATE(created_at)) <> MAX(DATE(created_at))
  ) x
```

If create_at has no time you can ditch the call to DATE

Side note, if a customer purchases at 1 second to midnight and 1 second past midnight, it's a very similar time frame but still an upsell according to your rules. Perhaps you should make the rule "at least 24h between the first and last sell" - I'll leave how to do that as an exercise for you; it's a simple modification

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS ( 
select distinct date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m_%d') as day,  user_id, product_id 
from transactions 
group by user_id
having count(distinct date(created_at) > 1 and count(distinct product_id) >1 
) 

SELECT day, count(user_id) 
from cte 
group by day
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be more easier for others to understand if you added an explanation of how it works to your answer.